# Multi axes timeseries line graph using matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create multi axis line chart where the x-axis are dates using matplotlib. As you can see in the picture below, the lines are close but all seem to be finishing on the left axis which is not correct.

Here is my code:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2= ax.twinx()
ax2.set_frame_on(True)
ax2.patch.set_visible(False)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

years = YearLocator()   # every year
months = MonthLocator()  # every month
yearsFmt = DateFormatter('%Y')

ax.plot_date(df.Date,df.A, fmt="r-")
ax.plot_date(df.Date,df.B, fmt="b-")
ax2.plot_date(df.Date,df.C, fmt="y-")
ax2.plot_date(df.Date,df.D, fmt="g-")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax.autoscale_view()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax2.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=10, rotation='vertical')
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=10, rotation='vertical')
ax.fmt_xdata = DateFormatter('%b\n%Y')
ax2.fmt_xdata = DateFormatter('%b\n%Y')
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=10, rotation='vertical')
ax.set_ylabel('(%)')
ax2.set_ylabel('(%)')
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
plt.title('Chart 1. ', fontsize=8, weight= 'bold')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Chart 1]

Answer (score 0):

need to use df1= df.sort_values(by='Date'). When i took a closer look at the data, there were a few dates out of order towards the end of the dataset that were causing the plot to revert back to 2002, causing the line to move towards the left of the graph.